# Javascript scroll and validation form

Tags: javascript

i would like to inform guest that he skip important form section.
That's why i want to change background color div to some else when he scroll and did not checked anyone input or write text to input

I wrote some like this

```
$(function(){
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#questrow1').offset().top - -100) && document.getElementsByClassName("wiztype").checked = false; {
        $("#questrow1").addClass('redback');
    }
});
});
```

Without that

```
&& document.getElementsByClassName("wiztype").checked = false;
```

Colorize is fine but checking inputs must works.

Answer (score 0):

`=` will not compare value and rather assign it. Here's updated expression -

```
$(function() {
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if (($(this).scrollTop() >= ($('#questrow1').offset().top - -100)) && !document.getElementsByClassName("wiztype").checked) {
      $("#questrow1").addClass('redback');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`= false` is not a comparison but an assignment. You'll want `==` (or simply a negation of the checked property since you want `false`).

However, `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, so you'll need to loop over all of them.

Also `- -100` is just `+ 100`

```
$(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("wiztype");
        var hasChecked = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i) {
            if(checkboxes.item(i).checked) {
                hasChecked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#questrow1').offset().top + 100 && !hasChecked) {
            $("#questrow1").addClass('redback');
        }
    });
});
```